# Is there a verb to be omitted?

Tags: verbs

Every time I go to social media, I get questions about the correctness of the English language and I wonder if there is an omitted verb to be between a noun and the main verb, for example someone spreading rumors of me. So is there a verb to be? I often see comments like Facebook, tiktok, YouTube etc

Sheeps saying dam he hits as hard as I do.

"Someone spreading rumors of me.

There's this river flowing through the middle of this desert.

"They be making money"

She received a letter containing important information.

A noun phrase referring is present participle functioning as an adjective

I saw a painting hanging on the wall.

Hanging, referring’ spreading, containing, saying,flowing

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to be asking about four or five different constructions, some of which are grammatical in standard English and some of which are not. this isn't the for mat of questions that we accept here. Please narrow the scope of your questions.

Comment: Is there is omit verb to be ? When verb to Be is /are was / were, is omit

Comment: Please narrow this down and also say where these came from. Some are likely AAVE; others are just participial phrases.

Comment: In *I saw a painting hanging on the wall*, no verbs are omitted. In *they be making money*, the verb *be* is in the wrong tense, but not omitted, because of the dialect spoken by the writer. In *Someone spreading rumors of me*, the verb *to be* is indeed omitted. In *There's this river flowing through the middle of this desert* and *She received a letter containing important information*, no verbs are omitted; these sentences are correct. This is a jumble of different constructions, which have relatively little in common.

Comment: If you're quoting something please put quotation marks at the start and end of the quote. Otherwise we can't tell what is a quotation and what is part of your question.

Comment: peter Shor  Please identify these three  questions ? one is referring, one is hanging, and one is following, e.g. There's this river flowing through the middle of this desert. 2 A noun phrase referring is present participle functioning as an adjective. 3 There's this river flowing through the middle of this desert.